# How to make an else condition work in PHP?

Tags: php

I have written PHP code with many nested `if` conditions. I just want to display an alert for an exceptional condition along with the `if` conditions.

Here is my source code:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
    $query ="SELECT * FROM user where username='.$username.' AND pass='.$password.'";

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $counted = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if (($counted === 1) && 
        ($row['username'] === $username) && 
        ($row['password'] === $password))
    {
        session_destroy();
        session_start();
        echo "message";
    } else {
        do_alert("Exceptional alert");
    }
} else {
    do_alert("Exceptional alert");
}
```

These two else conditions are not working. I don't know really where my mistake is.

Comment: @lolka There are two nested `if`s, which is just hardly obvious due to **missing indentation** (*hint hint Devarajan*).

Comment: Do you get any errors on this? What results do you get?

Comment: not working is not really a clear . Next of, maybe you should santize and protect your variables as well. As well, you dont have a query, so off course, you wont get anything back on that part. If I maybe so bold, what is this `do_alert` thing you have? (asuming it's a function)

Comment: OT with what asked here but worth mentioning: you should not use `mysql_` to deal with your database. It's deprecated and unsafe. Instead, use `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: @Dorvalla The IF . . .  ELSE statements look fine. I agree its worth checking if the do_alert is dropping the ball.

Comment: @deceze Oh, I see, sorry. Removed my comment.

Comment: @lolka_bolka : I meant i have placed only one ELSE for the both for testing. It doesn't work

Comment: @lolka_bolka : The indentation are ok. I am using an advanced editor "Netbean". I have missed to indent when i type it hear. thank you anyway!

Comment: @Dorvalla : I have replaced to echo"message"; I see it display nothing for the exception ELSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may have to do with your `do_alert` down in your code. Follow me through the code.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {  // if not empty
    $query ="";                                // this is an empty query
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);          // returns nada
    $counted = mysql_num_rows($query);         // gives nada back

    if (($counted === 1) && ($row['username'] === $username) && ($row['password'] === $password)) {                // completely useless at this point cause no row is returned

        session_destroy();
        session_start();
        echo "message";                        

    } else {                                  // this will not be executed
        do_alert("Exceptional alert");       
    }

} else {                                     // this will be executed
    do_alert("Exceptional alert");           // where is this function defined?
}
```

okay i commented on your code where it goes wrong. As you see it happens already on the first if, so it should return the last else. Since I dont know where your do_alert code is defined, my guess is that this is your error.

Try replacing it first with an echo like this: `echo "I am a super duper evil monkey";` and see if that works.

**edit**

since you added your query now, i 'd like to point out as well that you should sanitize your input. This to make it more safe. However the term safe here is kind of irralevant, cause you re using an outdated `mysql` set. (`mysqli / pdo` are the ways to go now)

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

why? simple. Look at this!

```
$_POST['username'] = 'awesome';
$_POST['password'] = "' OR ''='";
```

it would turn up something then like this.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='awesome' AND password='' OR ''=''
```

And this would mean, everybody could log in, cause blank is always blank. Just as a headsup.

More information here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

**edit 2**

```
// very first thing you do if you work with sessions, is actually starting it. you dont do this in your if else statement, cause you could not benefit of the session variable on a later stage on this page.

session_start();

// these variables come from a form with a form name, so we are going to do a check if indeed this came from that form.


$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

if (!empty($username) && 
    !empty($password)) {  
    $query ="SELECT name, password FROM user WHERE name='".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'"; 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);          
    $counted = mysql_num_rows($query);         

    if (($counted === 1) && 
        ($row['username'] === $username) && 
        ($row['password'] === $password)) {                

        echo "message";                        
    } else {                                  
        echo "no entrees found";       
    }
} else {                                     
    echo "failed to input some variable";     
}
```

I cleaned some up in my own words, you may have to fiddle with the query, and further i fixed it a bit since you didnt use the session appropiately.

Now where it echo's the message, you should set a session variable, that you can destroy later when you log out. A session variable you can call in the session itself, on every page that has sessionstart() in it. Here you can check if it excists, if so then you are logged in. I hope this helps you out.

Comment: function do_alert($msg) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("' . $msg . '"); 
          </script>';
}

Comment: here is my function do_alert

Comment: did it spit out the echo as i asked? Cause if it didnt, your code may not have reached this block. The if else statement looks fine. Also, can you put that function above in your code as well, people might start asking about it too :)

Comment: I have already tested with echo instead of do_alert, not solved

Comment: so how does your code route to this point? Do you submit it somewhere? Do you have a live example? Did it work before? All in a day of debugging :)

Comment: Just now i have seen my echo"message" just after the page refreshed after i clicked my form submit

Comment: asuming you gave in the `mysql` statement in the php code, so block 2 should be triggered. Do you have an ajax call submitted to this, or is it pure php, cause then the page has to be refreshed where it is send to. You have to return the page to itself. If you keep refreshing in a session that is returned, you ll see always the same message. You have to destroy the session first to retry.

Comment: is there any idea to display my echo"message" of exception to display it properly after my form button click?

Comment: it's pure PHP, html form with post method, ok Let me try a session_destroy in my ELSE.

Comment: i have coded my ELSE condition like this else{
        session_destroy();
        do_alert('eeeeee');
    }

Comment: it doesn't display anything

Comment: okay first off. try `echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Alert!');</script>";` first instead of your function. your function may be in another file that is not called at that point. I cannot see the lay-out of your page at the moment, hence i asked if this version is somewhere online?

Comment: Not yet!  same as it was!

Comment: Sorry just now i have read query part of your comment, there is a query i have hided it. i displayed a query in my question now!

Comment: thank you very much, it works after i create the session seperatly when the begining of the code.